# Como resolver o seguinte erro: HTTP Status 500- Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jsp

Estou a tentar fazer uma aplicação web usando java,jsp,servlets e base de dados. Mas quando faço run as na Classe addClient.jsp aparece este erro:

> HTTP Status 500- Internal Server Error.

Já procurei na internet a forma de resolver e não encontro solução. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Criei uma Classe Contact,  um Servlet CreateClient, ConnectionFactory, ContactDAO e addClient.jsp.

Coloco o código de algumas das classes

classe Contact:

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private int telephoneNumber;

    public Contact() {

    }
    public Contact (String name, String email, String address, int phone) {
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.address=address;
        this.telephoneNumber=phone;
    }
    //Getters e Setters 
     ...
    }
```

classe ContactDAO:

```
public class ContactDAO {
    private Connection con;


    public Connection getConnection() {
    return con;
    }

    public ContactDAO() {
      ConnectionFactory conF = new ConnectionFactory();
      con=conF.getBDConnection();
    }

   public void addClient(Contact contact) {
    String sql= "INSERT INTO contatos" + "(nome,email,endereco,telefone)" + 
   "values (?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);


        stmt.setString(1,contact.getName());
        stmt.setString(2,contact.getEmail());
        stmt.setString(3,contact.getAddress());
        stmt.setInt(4,contact.getTelephoneNumber());    


        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }     
}
```

classe ConnectionFactory:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {


public Connection getBDConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    System.out.println("Testing access to BD MySQL\n");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root", "");
        System.out.println("Connection successful!!!"); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SQLException");
    }
    return con;
}

public void closeConnection(Connection con) {
    try {
     con.close();
     System.out.println("\n Connection successfully close!!!");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("SQLException");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tem o stacktrace da log do servidor? Posta aqui para ajudar o pessoal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando para o seu código, é possível notar um erro logo na variável `String sql`, onde o valor declarado para a variável não possui espaços entre si, dessa forma, removendo as palavras reservadas do SQL e também o nome da própria tabela 
a ser consultada. Talvez seja esse o grande causador do seu problema. Segue a proposta de correção:

```
public void addClient(Contact contact) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO contatos ");
    sql.append("(nome,email,endereco,telefone) "); 
    sql.append("values (?,?,?,?)");
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        ... //Restante de código omitido por não haver alteração
    }
}
```

O uso do `StringBuilder` é por questões de hábito pessoal por otimização de código e de performance (mesmo que nesse caso não seja um grande impacto, já é algo que trouxe para a minha programação).